# PHP: file_get_contents failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized

Tags: php, xml

I get the following Error message, when I try to use file_get_contents:
(URL changed).

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://user:password@1.1.1.1/test/test.xml?cmd=show&user=*) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized in /srv/www/htdocs/phonebook.php on line 50
```

If I call the URL I can the see in the browser the XML-File. There are no spaces between it. However, I don't get it. Why it doesnt work. PHP Version is 5.3.17. Should I use cUrl?

The syntax is:

```
$xml_echo = "http://".$user.":".$pass."@".$ip .$url;
echo $xml_echo;
$xml_string = file_get_contents($xml_echo);
```

Additional Problem which I get, and might have to do with the described one is, that I get an error when I try to use:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(utf8_encode($xml_string));
```

I also tried using: simplexml_load_string

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /srv/www/htdocs/phonebook.php:55 Stack trace: #0 /srv/www/htdocs/phonebook.php(55): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') #1 {main} thrown in /srv/www/htdocs/get_pbx_phonebook.php on line 55
```

Answer (score -1):

Oh, after posting it. I tried to use it with

> https://

instead of

> http://

and now it worked.

So, no help needed.